# How to correctly set Content Security Policy for Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Greets,

This is the manifest file that I have set up.

```
{
"manifest_version":2,
"name": "Hyperfect",
"version": "1.0",
"content_security_policy":  "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';",
"description": "Simple shopee extension for Hyperfect",
"browser_action":{
    "default_popup": "src/popup.html"
},
"content_scripts":[
    {
        "matches":[
            "https://seller.shopee.com.my/portal/sale/order/*"
        ],
        "run_at": "document_end",

        "js":[
            "src/script/jquery-3.6.0.js","src/script/content.js"
        ]
    }
],
"permissions":[
    "activeTab"
],
"background":{
    "scripts":["src/script/event.js"],
    "persistent": false
}
```

}

I have set the script-src to **'self' 'unsafe-inline' and any HTTPS: URL**.
But I still get this warning.

> Refused to load the script 'https://apis.google.com/*/scs/apps-static/*/js/k=oz.gapi.en.OxsXq8UvEOs.O/m=auth2,client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCN7FQWUE2nltJhOBLbHOeQiriRsIg/cb=gapi.loaded_0' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

Adding **https** value should allow me to load any sources from HTTPS URL, right?

Comment: `https` should be `https:`

Comment: i still get the same result. It seems like it only takes the first value, and it ignores 'unsafe-inline' and https:

Comment: I did to add the whole URL link, but still same

Comment: 1) Did you reload the extension? 2) In which file do you load the script?

Comment: 1) i did to reload
2) i save this in my local `https://apis.google.com/js/api.js` and the url script is loaded by this script

Comment: i load this on my popup.html

Comment: Try removing `'unsafe-inline'`, I think it's not supported. Also where do you see the warning?

Comment: still not working, so far only this warning i got

Comment: Where do you see the warning?

Comment: popup window inspector

Comment: right click extension and there has one inspect option

Comment: @wOxxOm i fixed it, need to add this -> `script-src-elem`